# Javascript: Finding highest value in Map() vs Object

Tags: javascript, maps

I've been using objects as hash tables and I've been getting the highest value from them by `Objects.keys(foo).reduce((a,b) => foo[a] > foo[b] ? a : b)` . However, I've switched to using Maps() .  What is the ideal way to iterate through a Map object to get the highest value?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can spread the [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) into `Math.max`:

```js
let m = new Map([['a', 2], ['b',4], ['c',6]])

console.log("Max:", Math.max(...m.values()))
```

If you need both the key and value, I think you are back to `reduce()` using the `entries()` for the map:

```js
let m = new Map([['a', 2], ['b',4], ['c',6]])

console.log([...m.entries()].reduce((a, e ) => e[1] > a[1] ? e : a))
```

Comment: Wow, I just love this answer.

Comment: won't that just return the highest value though w/o indicating the key?  Can I return the key with the highest value?

Comment: @user10108817 do you want the whole entry or just the key?

Comment: @charlietfl in this case, just the key...but it'd be nice to know how to return the whole entry as well for future use :)

Comment: Your approach is very straight forward, what if the values where objects, with some unique value like of the form { amount: 12, name: 'someName' }, and i wanted the one with max amount.

Comment: @EbiIgweze would change to `e[1].amount > a[1].amount` in the reduce entries version if max amount was what you wanted to find

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yeah, I can see the update now...that's fine.

Comment: @MarkMeyer ...just quick question, what does the `1` in `e[1] > a[1]` represent?

Comment: @user10108817 `Map.entries()` gives a list of `[key, value]` pairs. So `e[1]` and `a[1]` are the respective values from the current and current max entries. `e[0]` and `a[0]` would be the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know how much map improves from your previous method but here is the way to loop through a map object.

```js
    // create map
    var myMap = new Map();
    // add key value pairs
    myMap.set('twelve', 12);
    myMap.set('two', 2);
    myMap.set('eleven', 11 );
    myMap.set('three', 3);

    var getMax1 = function (someMap) {
      var maxValue;
      for (var [key, value] of someMap) {
         maxValue = (!maxValue || maxValue < value) ? value : maxValue;
      }
      return maxValue;
    }

    var getMax2 = function (someMap) {
      var maxValue;
      for (var key of someMap.keys()) {
        var value = someMap.get(key);
        maxValue = (!maxValue || maxValue < value) ? value : maxValue;
      }
      return maxValue;
    }

    console.log(getMax1(myMap)); // 12
    console.log(getMax2(myMap)); // 12
```